# Copy data from different MySQL databases tables and different column names

Tags: mysql, joomla

I need to import stories from a Geeklog database to a Joomla database. Both databases are on the same server. MySQL version is 5.1.65

I will call the Geeklog database **`mysite_gklg`** and the Joomla database **`mysite_joom`**.
The table for stories in Geeklog is **`gl_stories`** and the table in Joomla is **`jos_content`**.

I need to `INSERT` from Geeklog gl_stories the following Columns:

```
 date, title, introtext, hits, meta_description, meta_keywords.
```

These will be inserted into Joomla jos_content the following Columns:

```
created, title, introtext, hits, metadesc, metakey.
```

I'm looking for the proper syntax to run the MySQL query.
Sorry, I don't have much programming skill. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looking up some basic MySQL syntax along the lines of INSERT INTO jos_content (list, of, fields) VALUES ('your', 'various', 'values')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Geeklog.gl_stories (date, title, introrext, hits, meta_description, meta_keywords)    
   SELECT created, title, introtext, hits, metadesc, metakey
   FROM Joomla.jos_content;
```

No reason this should be so unreadable.

Comment: Worked great, @khuderm! Thanks, I've been struggling for hours. I did reverse the databases, I was moving date into Joomla from Geeklog.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO Geeklog.gl_stories(date,title,introrext,hits,meta_description,meta_keywords)
select created,title,introtext,hits,metadesc,metakey FROM Joomla.jos_content;